# Do not know how to implement circularly linked list with only last Node as reference

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I was asked to reimplement the way a linked list was defined. The task is to: remove the reference to the first node in the LinkedList class so that I only keep track of the last element in the list. I am also asked to make the next() reference of the last element to the first element so that this linked list becomes a circular linked list. Is there an elegant way to do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class LinkedList
{  
   private Node last;

   /** 
      Constructs an empty linked list.
   */
   public LinkedList()
   {  
      last = null;
   }

   /**
      Returns the first element in the linked list.
      @return the first element in the linked list
   */
   public Object getFirst()
   {  
      if (last == null) 
         throw new NoSuchElementException();
      return last.next.data;
   }

   /**
      Removes the first element in the linked list.
      @return the removed element
   */
   public Object removeFirst()
   {  
      if (last == null) 
         throw new NoSuchElementException();
      Object element = last.next.data;
      last.next = last.next.next;
      return element;
   }

   /**
      Adds an element to the front of the linked list.
      @param element the element to add
   */
   public void addFirst(Object element)
   {  
        if( last == null ){
          last = new Node();
          last.data = element;
          last.next = last;
        }
        else{
      Node newNode = new Node();
      newNode.data = element;
      last.next = newNode;
      newNode.next = last.next;
      }
   }

   /**
      Returns an iterator for iterating through this list.
      @return an iterator for iterating through this list
   */
   public ListIterator listIterator()
   {  
      return new LinkedListIterator();
   }

   class Node
   {  
      public Object data;
      public Node next;
   }

   class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator
   {  
      private Node position;
      private Node previous;
      /**
         Constructs an iterator that points to the front
         of the linked list.
      */
      public LinkedListIterator()
      {  
         position = null;
         previous = null;
      }

      /**
         Moves the iterator past the next element.
         @return the traversed element
      */
      public Object next()
      {  
         if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
         previous = position; // Remember for remove

         if (position == null)
            position = last.next;
         else
            position = position.next;

         return position.data;
      }

      /**
         Tests if there is an element after the iterator position.
         @return true if there is an element after the iterator position
      */
      public boolean hasNext()
      {  
         if (position == null)
            return last != null;
         else
            return position.next != null;
      }

      /**
         Adds an element before the iterator position
         and moves the iterator past the inserted element.
         @param element the element to add
      */
      public void add(Object element)
      {  
         if (position == null)
         {
            addFirst(element);
            position = last;
         }
         else
         {  
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.data = element;
            newNode.next = position.next;
            position.next = newNode;
            position = newNode;
         }
         previous = position;
      }

      /**
         Removes the last traversed element. This method may
         only be called after a call to the next() method.
      */
      public void remove()
      {  
         if (previous == position)
            throw new IllegalStateException();

         if (position == last)
         {
            removeFirst();
         }
         else 
         {  
            previous.next = position.next;
         }
         position = previous;
      }

      /**
         Sets the last traversed element to a different value. 
         @param element the element to set
      */
      public void set(Object element)
      {
         if (position == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
         position.data = element;
      }
   }
}
```

---

This was the original code:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
   A linked list is a sequence of nodes with efficient
   element insertion and removal. This class 
   contains a subset of the methods of the standard
   java.util.LinkedList class.
*/
public class LinkedList
{  
   private Node first;

   /** 
      Constructs an empty linked list.
   */
   public LinkedList()
   {  
      first = null;
   }

   /**
      Returns the first element in the linked list.
      @return the first element in the linked list
   */
   public Object getFirst()
   {  
      if (first == null) 
         throw new NoSuchElementException();
      return first.data;
   }

   /**
      Removes the first element in the linked list.
      @return the removed element
   */
   public Object removeFirst()
   {  
      if (first == null) 
         throw new NoSuchElementException();
      Object element = first.data;
      first = first.next;
      return element;
   }

   /**
      Adds an element to the front of the linked list.
      @param element the element to add
   */
   public void addFirst(Object element)
   {  
      Node newNode = new Node();
      newNode.data = element;
      newNode.next = first;
      first = newNode;
   }

   /**
      Returns an iterator for iterating through this list.
      @return an iterator for iterating through this list
   */
   public ListIterator listIterator()
   {  
      return new LinkedListIterator();
   }

   class Node
   {  
      public Object data;
      public Node next;
   }

   class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator
   {  
      private Node position;
      private Node previous;
      /**
         Constructs an iterator that points to the front
         of the linked list.
      */
      public LinkedListIterator()
     {  
         position = null;
         previous = null;
      }

      /**
         Moves the iterator past the next element.
         @return the traversed element
      */
      public Object next()
      {  
         if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
         previous = position; // Remember for remove

         if (position == null)
            position = first;
         else
            position = position.next;

         return position.data;
      }

      /**
         Tests if there is an element after the iterator position.
         @return true if there is an element after the iterator position
      */
      public boolean hasNext()
      {  
         if (position == null)
            return first != null;
         else
            return position.next != null;
      }    

      /**
         Adds an element before the iterator position
         and moves the iterator past the inserted element.
         @param element the element to add
      */
      public void add(Object element)
      {  
         if (position == null)
         {
            addFirst(element);
            position = first;
         }
         else
         {  
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.data = element;
            newNode.next = position.next;
            position.next = newNode;
            position = newNode;
         }
         previous = position;
      }

      /**
         Removes the last traversed element. This method may
         only be called after a call to the next() method.
      */
      public void remove()
      {  
         if (previous == position)
            throw new IllegalStateException();

         if (position == first)
         {
            removeFirst();
         }
         else 
         {  
            previous.next = position.next;
         }
         position = previous;
      }

      /**
         Sets the last traversed element to a different value. 
         @param element the element to set
      */
      public void set(Object element)
      {
         if (position == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
         position.data = element;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you don't have a working code sample, posting a small amount of code with which you are confused is more useful.  If you do have a working code sample, you may consider posting this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is modify the Node class to something like this:

```
class Node {
    // point to the previous node in the linked list
    private Node prev;
    private Object data;   
}
```

So now your linked list is sort of backward linked, and in LinkedList you only have to keep track of the "tail", and you can follow the links from the tail to get any node of the linked list, right?

Now to make the LinkedList a circle, all you need to do is to make sure the "prev" field of the head node(first node) of your linked list is always pointing to your tail. Here is how to do it:

1. When the list is empty, do nothing :)
2. When the first node is added to the list, point "tail" in your LinkedList to it, also point "prev" of the node to itself. It's because the node is both tail and head, right?
3. When add more nodes, first find the head node in the LinkedList by following links from the "tail" all the way until you find the node that links to "tail". Then add the new node, and update the links of your head/tail node accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Give a more robust implementation of the circularly linked list data structure
of Section 3.4.1, which throws an appropriate exception if an illegal
operation is attempted